# PHP: Is the CRC from ZipArchive::statIndex() unique enough to be used to detect duplicate files in many zips?

Tags: php, zip, crc, php-ziparchive, crc32

If I have multiple zip files and I loop through the contents of each to find unique files, will the CRC value be the same for the same file in different zips?

The [statindex](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.statindex.php) method on ZipArchive returns an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [name] => foobar/baz
    [index] => 3
    [crc] => 499465816
    [size] => 27
    [mtime] => 1123164748
    [comp_size] => 24
    [comp_method] => 8
)
```

To be honest, the filesize will probably be unique enough for my needs, but to be safe I was looking for another way to detect uniqueness.

From what I can tell the only alternative would be to extract and then use the [file-hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php) method, but this would be alot slower than just being able to use something that's made available from the ZipArchive class.

In my case I have a directory of about 230,000 images built from 30,000 zips with around 30 images in each zip and I want to create a database of which images came from which zip, and I know that there will be lots of duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A two stages approach

The CRC is, [as far as I can tell](https://libzip.org/documentation/zip_stat_index.html), a 32 bit unsigned integer (4,294,967,295 values). For bigger files, like images, we can assume it has a flat random distribution. I would combine this with the `size` to get a *hopefully unique* string:

```
$stat = $zip->statIndex($index);
$str = $stat["crc"] . $stat["size"];
```

If the compression method is the same in all ZIP files you could add the compressed size:

```
$stat = $zip->statIndex($index);
$str = $stat["crc"] . $stat["size"] . $stat["comp_size"];
```

That would make it *highly unlikely* that two different images result in the same string, but just like with real hashes there is still *a very small change* that it will return *the same string for two different images*.

I don't think that is acceptable.

However, if two images return the same string you can still inspect them more closely to check whether they are indeed the same. You could start with one of the better [hashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.hash.php), but why not simply do a byte-by-byte comparison? This way you can actually be *absolutely sure* about the uniqueness of your images.

Sure, this will be slower than just relying on the stats, but I think you have to agree that this is better than having a very small change of misidentifying images.

So my approach here would be to do a rough check with the `crc` and `size` first. If these are the same then I would actually compare the files to make sure they are really the same. This way I never run the change of assuming two images are the same, because their `crs/size`'s are the same, when they are not.

Answer (score 2):

No, a 32bit CRC collides too easily. Consider comparing the CRC and the size (and preferably also the compressed size and the compression method) - if all 4 are the same it's safe enough to assume identical files.

However, what's your definition of "duplicate"?

- Two picture files can have the identical payload (the actual photo) but different metadata (caption, comment...) - in that case you'd hash portions of the files yourself, so metadata is ignored.
- Two picture files can portrait the same scene, but have different dimensions (i.e. 800x600 versus 1600x1200) or a different compression (lossy, lossless, interlaced...) - in that case you have to visually interpret them.
- Two picture files can result in rendering the same display, but have different formats (i.e. PNG, TIFF, JPEG, WEBP...) - in that case you want to compare the rendered bitmaps of them.

As you see: extracting/uncompressing the files would make you able to operate more precisely, first of all using your favorite software for detecting duplicates.